# How to Select and Move a rectangle in a pictureBox?

Tags: c#, select, draw, move

Just wondering how I would go about actually selecting the rectangle I draw and then being able to move it around? I would also need to delete it but I can work that part out. Just a bit lost as to what I need to do. Pseudo Code or actual code is fine, just a stepping stone would be appreciated.

Also, if anyone else knows how to actually show the rectangles X and Y in a listBox that would be great as well. But at the moment, the top question is priority.

This is how I draw my rectangles:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (buttonDown)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                draw = true;
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageFile);
                Pen pen1 = new Pen(color, 4);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen1, e.X - 5, e.Y - 5, 5, 5);
                g.Save();
                pictureBox1.Image = imageFile;
            }                
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Is there only one rectangle in the picture box or there are other paintings as well?

Comment: What's the issue?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve such behavior, you will have to store information about the rectangles. E.g. in a class like this:

```
class Rect
{
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
    int Width { get; set; }
    int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Note that there is already a `Rectangle` type. You can use this as well, but since it is a structure, you have to handle selection differently.

Now you can create a list of rectangles and the selection:

```
List<Rect> rects = new List<Rect>();
Rect selectedRect = null;
```

Displaying these rects in a listbox is pretty easy. Just bind the listbox's items to the list. You may need to override `ToString()` in order to get a user-friendly output.

Drawing the rectangles could look like the following:

```
foreach(var r in rects)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(pen1, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
    ...
}
```

You can highlight the selected rect. E.g. with a different pen or another rect around it:

```
if(selectedRect == r)
    g.DrawRectangle(pen1, r.x - 5, r.Y - 5, r.Width + 10, r.Height + 10);
```

In the `MouseDown` event or another appropriate event you can set the selection to the clicked rect:

```
foreach(var r in rects)
    if(e.X >= r.X && e.X <= r.X + r.Width && e.Y >= r.Y && e.Y <= r.Y + r.Height)
        selectedRect = r;
```

To move the rect, you would save the point of the rect that has been clicked (distance from top left corner). In the mouse move event, check if the left button is down and reposition the `selectedRect` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, made it a lot easier to understand!